# deliveryMode=persistent and broker configured with persistent=false

Tags: activemq-classic

What happens if a broker is configured not to support persistent messages and a client delivers a message with delivery mode PERSISTENT ?

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off persistence on the broker side then Messages sent with persistence set to true aren't persisted.  The broker uses a MemoryPersistenceAdapter and those messages are kept in memory but are lost once the broker is restarted.  You normally only use this setting when unit testing, or in cases where you know your broker doesn't require persistence.